# JDBC COPY with ant

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc, ant

I have a project with Spring, Hibernate and PostgreSQL and have to use ANT to create schema with data:

```
        <sql driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
            classpath="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres"
            userid="postgres"
            password="pw123"
            autocommit="true"
            src="src/main/sql/dbbackup.sql">
        </sql>
```

but I get this error:

```
C:\Users\<user>\<workspace>\<Project>\antdb.xml:22: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: COPY from stdin failed: The JDBC driver currently does not support COPY operations.
```

Don't know if somehow we could use postgresql.copy class here?

Comment: PgJDBC doesn't support `COPY` *directly*, but it does via the `CopyManager` API you can get from `PGConnection`. Trouble is, you can't use that from a plain `SQL` file. Personally, I'd shell out to `psql` to run `.sql` files.

Comment: I could use `psql` but how can i use it with ant?

Comment: Ant supports running shell commands via the exec task.

Comment: Maybe you could help me a bit with that. I but did `exec` like this `"><exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="psql -p 5433 -U postgres -d etsydb -f
        src/main/sql/etsydbbackup.sql" />
  </exec>
` Nothing happens..

Comment: got the answer! - <exec executable="psql">

<arg value="-p" />
       <arg value="5433" />
       <arg value=".. </exec>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PgJDBC doesn't support `COPY` directly, but it does via the `CopyManager` API you can get from the `PGConnection` interface of the `java.sql.Connection` returned by PgJDBC.

Unfortunately, you can't use that from a plain SQL file where you mix `COPY` operations in with other commands.

Personally, I'd shell out to `psql` to run `.sql` files using the Ant `<exec>` task. That way you can include `COPY` data in-line in your SQL files.

It'd be nice to enable PgJDBC to handle `COPY`, but it's not easy. It's effectively a different protocol mode in PostgreSQL, and it doesn't make much sense to use the usual JDBC interfaces with prepared statements, execute, etc, for it. We could provide an `execSQLScript` on the custom `PGconnection` but that wouldn't help you out much because things like Ant's `<sql>` task wouldn't use it. You'd  have to write a custom task.

Instead, PgJDBC would have to pretty much lie to clients - when it entered `COPY` mode after a `COPY` command, it'd have to ignore the JDBC spec and not really do what it was supposed to in response to JDBC statement executes. This would be likely to break all sorts of things.

So - for now, by far the easiest option is to just exec the `psql` command to do what you want.

Comment: I don't know the driver in detail, but I think `copy from stdin` *could* be integrated in a "JDBC compliant" way through a PreparedStatement. Something like `copy from from stdin ?` where the `?` marks the data. The data itself would then be provided through `PreparedStatement.setCharacterStream()`. In the background the driver would then hand over everything to the CopyManager.

Comment: Very interesting point. Whether that'd work with code like Ant's `<sql>` task and other tools that just see a blob of SQL with the copy data inline, though ... not sure.

Comment: I agree that with the Ant task and interactive SQL things probably won't work (well) - mainly because they would need to handle the (non-standard) delimiter that marks the end of the data.